# Accessing External Object data using custom controller and simple page - gives INVALID_QUERY_LOCATOR: invalid query locator

Tags: visualforce, lightning-connect

I am trying to surface external object data within a VisualForce page and getting

**INVALID_QUERY_LOCATOR: invalid query locator**

Here is my code

Controller code

```
public class TestExternalDataCustomController {

    public ApexPages.StandardSetController setCon {

        get {

            if (setCon == null) {

                setCon = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator(

                    [SELECT Id, Company_name__c FROM public_companylist__x LIMIT 10]));

            }

            return setCon;

        }

        set;

    }

    public List<public_companylist__x> getCompanies() {

        return (List<public_companylist__x>) setCon.getRecords();

    }

}
```

Page

```
<apex:page controller="TestExternalDataCustomController">

    <apex:pageBlock>

        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!companies}" var="c">

                       <apex:column value="{!c.Id}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!c.company_name__c}"/>

           <apex:column value="{!c.externalid}"/>

        </apex:pageBlockTable>

    </apex:pageBlock>

</apex:page>
```

Any ideas? Is this even possible, it seems a pretty basic example to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use StandardSetController mechanism with external data .The mechanisms described in the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_connector_paging.htm?search_text=external) are as follows

1. [Server Driven Pattern](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_connector_querymore_server_driven_paging.htm)

> With server-driven paging, the external system controls the paging and ignores any batch boundaries or page sizes that are specified in queries. To enable server-driven paging, declare the QUERY_PAGINATION_SERVER_DRIVEN capability in your DataSource.Provider class.

2. [Client Driven Pattern](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_connector_querymore_client_driven_paging.htm?search_text=external)

> With client-driven paging, you use LIMIT and OFFSET clauses to page through result sets.
>   If the external system can return the total size of the result set for each query, declare the QUERY_TOTAL_SIZE capability in your DataSource.Provider class. Make sure that each search or query returns the totalSize value in the DataSource.TableResult. If the total size is larger than the number of rows that are returned in the batch, we generate a nextRecordsUrl link and set the done flag to false. We also set the totalSize in the TableResult to the value that you supply.

There is an [example](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_connector_example_google_books.htm?search_text=external) in apex guide to assist with .

Comment: Thanks Mohith for responding. Are there any community blogs which show / step through the client side pattern?

Comment: Mohith I have discovered a pattern which allows me to interact with the external data like I originally wanted. If you come up the External Data object from a standard object you can bypass most of the restrictions. If your SOQL you basically hook into relationship query to access the data. I can now query against External Company name as one example using LIKE.

Comment: @MichaelGill Please share the same with community here as another answer .Community will love you :)

Answer (score 1):

I have found a way to interact with External Object data using standard set controller and other more traditional VF design patterns.

If you base your SOQL query logic around a standard object which has contains lookup to the external data object - then you can perform most of what you need to do in VF

```
QueryCompany = 'SELECT Id, Name, ExternalCompanyData__r.ExternalId, ExternalCompanyData__r.Company_name__c  ' +
               ' FROM CompanyWrapper__c ';
```

Now it does open up a serious question about whether this option even makes sense, because you need to integrate the data from the external system to at least make the link. I'm still exploring things.